# Vertical strip line

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Trying to create a vertical strip line on a particular date on my x-axis, like the below picture, which is a reporting services chart which has been copied into excel and then the strip line put on top.

[image]

I Have tried: In Striplines on the x-axis I have set  the Interval Offset to the following

```
=IIF(Fields!yyyy_mm.value = "Dec, 2016", 1 ,0)
```

and Width as 2, but I'm getting nothing show up on my chart.

Comment: Try making your date a valid value from your list (e.g. it looks like it should be "2016-12" instead of "Dec, 2016").

Comment: Dis you try this, StripLines property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/highlight-chart-data-by-adding-strip-lines-report-builder-and-ssrs
Start with a fresh report.

Comment: Also, it could perhaps be the date with the comma "Dec, 2016" format that is not matching.

Comment: Is `yyyy_mm` in your dataset a date or text value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `yyyy-mm` is a **text value**, the IntervalOffset should be a number that aligns to the number of X-axis categories. An IntervalOffset of 3 will start the StripLine on your third month, or 3.5 will start it between your third and fourth month.

If you don't know where on your X-axis December 2016 will be, you can use an expression and count the X-axis values smaller than the one you want:

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!YYYY_MM.Value <= "2016-12", Fields!YYYY_MM.Value, nothing)) -0.5
```

---

If `yyyy-MM` is a **date value**, you can use a date as the IntervalOffset value. You will need to convert it to an OLE Automation date value, but the expression is simple:

```
=CDate("01-DEC-2016").ToOADate
```

Comment: The savior once again, thank you. Just a couple of questions...is there a way to bring it to the front because currently some of it is hidden by upper and lower control limits?  and is there a way of labelling it?

Comment: I don't think you can set StripLines to appear over values, but you could give your control limits a colour with transparency. Use the More Colors... window, or use an ARGB hex value like `#7a00ff00`.

Comment: In the StripLines menu, use the Title property of a StripLine to give it a label. Other properties there can control the font, alignment etc. of the title.